# Read from binary file > data into class object, missing data

Tags: c++, class, object, fstream

I'm currently making a file that reads ASCII file to read binary file instead. It has to put data into an object named Arragements and Customers. However, something is missing. It does not read the first line of the files.

It is reading everything correctly (it seems), except the fact that it doesn't read the first line of the file at all, and instead it adds 5 zeros at the end when it is supposed to not be anything there. In other words, it is not reading everything. Any big mistakes made? I'm changing the code **from** reading a **ASCII** file **to** read a **BINARY** file instead. If it make any changes, I've added how the readTicketsFromFile looked like when it was written to read ASCII file blow.

Here's the code when reading from ASCII: https://pastebin.com/WswHzpxM

The file format is (10 lines total): 
< nr (2) > < amount tickets(4) > < price(3) > < title(30) >

Here's what I ried to make, "translating" the code to read same file in BINARY (It is obviously converted to BINARY file):

```
 #include <fstream>                     //  ifstream, ofstream
 #include <iostream>                    //  cout
 #include <cstring>                     //  strcpy
 #include <cstdlib>                     //  (s)rand
 using namespace std;

 const int ARRLEN = 35;

    // CLASSES
    class Arrangement  {
      private:
        char title[ARRLEN];               //  Arrangement title/name
        int  price;                         //  Price pr. ticket
        int  amountSpaces;                   //  Amounts of spaces/tickets left
        int  amountSold;                     //  Amounts of tickets sold so far
        int  totalTicketsOrdered;       //  Total amount of tickets
        int  totalCustomersOrdered;          //  Amount of customers wanting a ticket

      public:
        Arrangement();
        void update(char titt[], int ant, int pri);
        void updateAmountWishedTickets(int antBill);
        void updateAmountSold(int ant);
        bool needPull();
        int  amountLeft();
        int  amountOrdered();
        void write()  
        {
         cout 
              << '\n' << price << "\t"
              << amountSpaces << "\t" 
              << amountSold << "\t"
              << totalTicketsOrdered 
              << "\t" << totalCustomersOrdered
              << '\t' << title;  
        }
    };



    // READ FROM FILE 1
    void readTicketsFromFile() {
        char title[ARRLEN];
        int  nr, amount, price;     // Variables 3 first "spaces" of the file
        int size = 0;

        //    post/linje på filen.
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("tickets.res", ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (infile.is_open()) {
            infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
            size = (int)infile.tellg() / sizeof(Arrangement);
            cout << "\n# in file: " << size << endl;   // Prints out: 10


            // Read from file, supposed to read everything from the file
            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
                infile.seekg(i * sizeof(Arrangement));
                infile.read((char *)& arrangementer[i], sizeof(Arrangement));
                cout << '\n' << i << " read: \n";
                arrangementer[i].write();       // Used to see what what's inside the object, 1. missing.
            }

        }
        else cout << "Couldn't open the file";
        infile.close();
    }

    int main() {
        readTicketsFromFile();
        return 0;
    }
```

What it shoud look like:
[https://i.gyazo.com/69c5560766c33ebc15cac25e13b4de72.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzqRG.png)

What it looks like:
[https://i.gyazo.com/a9081f65ff629f3b57cb2c20750087b5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSoTT.png)

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)` combined with `infile.seekg(i * sizeof(Arrangement));` looks a lot to me like you are skipping the first entry in the file and possibly reading one past the end.

Comment: Check your indexing.

Comment: This is what I have tried:
- Set int = 0; and keep <= size;   (no difference)
- Set int = 0; and <= size+1; (missing 1 at top and bottom)
- Set int = 0 and < size; (no difference)

Comment: Do a quick count on your fingers of how many loop iterations there are in `for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)`

Comment: The thing is that I got 10 lines in the file, which int size finds out. So whenever I set for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) it should work, as that is 10 lines. However, as I have said, it does not work.

Comment: @MemyselfandI -- `Arrangement` [is not a POD type](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03c7c31275be321b), so all of this binary file reading / writing may be invalid to begin with.  Remove the `Arrangement` constructor, and the type becomes `POD`.  Unless the type is `C` layout compatible, you cannot simply use these techniques of binary file reading / writing of that type.

Comment: How would I read from a binary file then? If I have understood POD right, they cannot have constructors? I'm not allowed to change the data inside the class, so it has to be like that. How could I read that file in then?

Added pics in the main post.

Comment: All files are "binary".  What you want to do is read a bunch of bytes and hopefully you are recreating the object.   That can't work reliably if the type you're blasting the bytes to is not a POD type or `C` layout compatible.  C++ doesn't work this way, and I've seen many posts similar to yours where the poster is trying this, to no avail.

Comment: @MemyselfandI -- My advice -- remove the constructor for `Arrangement`, whether or not you're allowed to change the data inside the class.  This is for *your* experiment.  Then take the advice that others have stated, i.e. start from 0 and read / write up to `size - 1`.  Does your code work then?  If it does, then bingo, you know what the problem is.

Comment: I removed the constructor, set the for loop to be  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) where size = 10, there are 10 lines. It reads 10 lines according to the condition inside the for loop. Still same issue as pictured in the main post. Weird.

Comment: @MemyselfandI You need to rewrite the `Arrangement` data using the "good" version (without the constructor) to the file first before you start reading it.  Did you do that?  Otherwise you will be reading data that was written with the "bad" `Arrangement` class.

Comment: I just removed the constructor. So how exactly do you do it the good way? Mind showing an example for 1 data?

Comment: @MemyselfandI -- I don't know how more simply to put this.  Write the data to the file first using the adjusted Arrangement class.  Then read the data from the file using the adjusted Arrangement class.  If you're saying someone just handed you a file and you're supposed to read it, then that's ridiculous -- you would have no idea how that file was created, what fields were / were not used, etc.  I'm assuming you're the one creating these files and having trouble reading them.

Comment: The file wasn't created by me, but the file formatting was given to me (as you can see in the post). It is written like this, so why can't I simply change it to infile.read:
for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
 outfile.write((char *)& arrangements[i], sizeof(Arrangement));